# Continue after Facebook Permission accept

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to do a code but only after the user accept the permission
He press the send score button and The flowing code.

For the first time running the appliaction the user accept and get the error and after the first click it works fine.

How can I synch the user accept Permission click and the other code ?

```
public void post_Score(View view){
    this.textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    //request Publish Permissions
    requestPublishPermissions(Session.getActiveSession());
    Bundle fbParams = new Bundle();
    randomScore = new Random().nextInt(1000000);
    fbParams.putString("score", "" + randomScore);
    Request postScoreRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),"me/scores",fbParams,HttpMethod.POST,new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {
                System.out.println("BAD");
                textView.setText("BAD " + error.getErrorMessage());

            } else {
                System.out.println("Your score is " + randomScore);
                textView.setText("Your score is " + randomScore);
                savingUserDetails();
            }
        }
    });
    Request.executeBatchAsync(postScoreRequest);
}
```

And the requestPublishPermissions function

```
private void requestPublishPermissions(Session session) {
    if (session != null && !session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")) {
        System.out.println("SEESION Permission");
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(mainFragment, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session.requestNewPublishPermissions call is asynchronous, which means that when it returns, it hasn't asked the user for the permissions yet, so the first time through, your subsequent Request will fail.

The right way to do this is add a callback to the NewPermissionsRequest (see the javadocs for the NewPermissionsRequest, there should be a setCallback method), and move your Request code into the callback.